# Android dynamic viewpager

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am fetching data from server like different types of user profile I need to display that using the viewpager fragments. I need to dynamically add fragments and display that profiles. Kindly help with any tutorials it would be grateful.